# How to get disk usage or sizes of files in a directory in a HDFS filesystem using Scala

Tags: scala, hdfs

I am trying to get the size of the files in a HDFS directory in Scala. I can do the following in REPL:

```
Seq("/usr/bin/hdfs", "dfs", "-du", "-s", "/tmp/test").!
```

but I cannot store the result into a value.  How can I get the size of the files in a directory in Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` method you're using comes from [`ProcessBuilder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html).
(`Seq[String]` is being implicitly converted to a `ProcessBuilder`, thus granting you access to `!`).

```
/** Starts the process represented by this builder, 
  * blocks until it exits, and returns the exit code.
  */
abstract def !: Int
```

If you want the output, use a different method, like `!!`

```
/** Starts the process represented by this builder, 
  * blocks until it exits, and returns the output as a String.
  */
abstract def !!: String
```

I recommend checking out the other methods defined on ProcessBuilder. I'm sure at least one of them will suit your needs.

Comment: That works. once I put the result with the !! into a value I could simply do the following to get the size val inputSize = duResult.split(" ")(0)

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend the use of https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files

```
import better.files._
import java.io.{File => JFile}

val size = File("/usr/bin/hdfs").size
println(size)
```

Comment: One of the requirements/requests is to not use any third party libraries.

Comment: @Andrew fair enough. For what it's worth, better-files doesn't have any transitive dependencies, so that's just the one.